# Exclude folder in coverage JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test, jacoco

Hitting the coverage it tries to parse me these folders, but I need it to only detect main and test, and exclude target.

[This is my actual coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrGQR.png)

I use JUnit, SonarQ, Maven, and Jacoco.

I have much DTOs and other classes I don't want to add...

Jacoco´s plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/target/generated-sources/xjc/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only report goal, I assume you already have `exec` file. You need to exclude classes generated by `xjc`, not the folders, something like `**/generated/**/*.class` where `generated` is one of the subpackage names.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</dataFile>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/model/**/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/infrastructure/**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad information that I provide, I have updated the post to see if there is a better understanding, thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: This still applies, move your `configuration` section to `execution` of report goal, and again - you are excluding folders, you need to exclude classes. `**/your/package/in/xjc/folder/**/*.class`

Comment: Love u, Thanks<3